# JSON Payload doesnt seem to be sending

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

My problem I'm pretty positive is simple, I must just be missing something.. just not sure what.

I can send GET and POST for granular elements (this=that kind of stuff), but a web service call I need to send data too, takes a raw JSON block, with no "key"

Heres the method I wrote:

```
-(NSData *)execute {

    // Smart Chooser ?
    if(PostData.count >0 || Payload != nil)
        [self setMethod:UPLINK_METHOD_POST];
    else
        [self setMethod:UPLINK_METHOD_GET];



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:self.connectionUrl
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:10];


    if([UPLINK_METHOD_GET isEqualToString:self.connectionMethod])
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    else
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    NSString *gData = [self compileGetData];
    NSString *pData = [self compilePostData];

    // if we have get data, set it into the URL string
    if(GetData.count > 0) {

        [self setURLWithString:[[self.connectionUrl absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:[@"?" stringByAppendingString:gData]]];
        [request setURL:self.connectionUrl];

    }

    // if we have post data, set it in the body
    if(PostData.count > 0) {
        const char *bytes = [[NSString stringWithString:pData] UTF8String];
        [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:strlen(bytes)]];

    }

    // Override any post data if a payload is already defined.
    if(Payload != nil) {

        [request setHTTPBody:[Payload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }

    NSLog(@"URL : %@", request.URL);


    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    if(err != nil)
        NSLog(@"here was an error: %@", err);


    return responseData;
}

-(NSDictionary *)executeAsJSON
{
    NSData *responseData = [self execute];
    NSError *e;
    return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
}
```

Ok SO, the way this thing works, is that it automatically sets whether the request is POST or GET depending on the data provided in the GetData, PostData, and Payload vars.

The request is GET by default, but turns into POST if PostData or Payload have anything in them.
The `compileGetData` and `compilePostData` mostly just bring back formatted strings with arrays of information combined, nothing special there.

But thats not where the problem is.

See, "Payload" overrides anything "PostData" had in it. If you had provided PostData elements into the class, it would just be overridden by a provided Payload if that does exist.

I needed to provide this to demonstrate the "workarea" as it exists right now, its not linearly provided information.

This is the area of interest:

```
// Override any post data if a payload is already defined.
if(Payload != nil) {

    //const char *plbytes = [[NSString stringWithString:Payload] UTF8String]; // this didn't work
    [request setHTTPBody:[Payload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // inline, doesn't work either

}
```

When I say "doesnt work", what I mean is, im getting back an error JSON array from the webservice that basically means "hey, wheres the payload?". If the request is not POST it comes back as a general error, so thats all working, the URL is then obviously correct.

I've used RESTConsole for Chrome to test the webservice to make sure its working properly, and it does.

I've also checked through the debugger the exact payload im sending, i copy+pasted that into RESTConsole, and it works there.

I'm.. honestly at a loss here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a web proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) (I personally preferr Charles due to it's ease of use, it's a 30-day trial though) and monitor the request you make from RESTConsole and the one you make from your app and see if they look the same.

Check any headers, line returns and anything else that looks different.

That's the best I can think of to start with

Comment: I checked out Charles, and I see the response data im sending and getting back.

Now, the interesting thing, is that when sent from the iPhone Simulator, I see a Warning sign, but when sending the exact same data (copied and pasted FROM Charles just to be sure) it come sback just fine. But the header information is slightly different

Comment: Charles is a great tool, and helped me realize that the problem stemmed from the Content-Type header. iPhone was sending it as form data, I needed to force it to application/json.   Thanks guys!

Comment: i can't even count the hours of debugging i've saved by using charles